# get_meta_data within a loop

Tags: query-posts

I'm trying to make a simple widget that displays a list of posts, and is followed by some metadata from each post.

Here is my code:
`$eventdate` contains the metadata i need to retrieve.

```
query_posts('');

if (have_posts()) : 
    echo "<ul>";
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $eventdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event-date', true);
        echo "<li>".get_the_title()." - ".$eventdate."</li>";
    endwhile;
    echo "</ul>";
endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

I read an old post on the wordpress support forums about custom loops like this, and I'm fairly certain that I'm not calling the $post_id properly, because if I manually insert a post_id it calls the correct data.. but either way I'm unsure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post this as an answer, and then accept it as correct (you'll have to wait 24 hours). It takes it off the unanswered pile, and makes it easier for people to identify the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I will, just waiting for the time to pass

Comment: You can post the answer immediately :D

Comment: If you're in the loop, it's a better practice to use `get_the_ID()` rather than declare global and use `$post->ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query_posts()` is for main query, it would be more wise to use `get_posts()` function to get you events.

```
// Modify get_posts args for your needs
$events = get_posts( array ( 'post_type' => 'events' ) );

if ( $events ) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $events as $event ) {
        $event_date = get_post_meta( $event->ID, 'event-date', true );

        echo '<li>' . get_the_title( $event->ID ) . ' - ' . $event_date . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debugged and realised that $post in $post->ID needed to be declared a global variable. Sorted.

Comment: Why is `get_the_ID()` better @Tom ?

Comment: Was it a nested loop?

Comment: only as nested as above code shows

Comment: @Northernlights `get_the_ID` does the same thing, calls global `$post` and returns `$post->ID`